# How to find node exists in JSON

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have following JSON

```
{"subscription": 
 {
 "callbackReference": "xyz" ,
 "criteria": "Vote",
 "destinationAddress": "3456" ,
  "notificationFormat" : "JSON"
 }
}
```

I want to check whether "notificationFormat" elements exits there using JSONPath expression. I can get the value of above element using following JSONPath expression.

```
$.subscription.notificationFormat
```

Can I use similar kind of expression which returns boolean value checking whether elements exists ?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Check at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: OK. What does this JSONPath expression return for a missing property? What does it return for a `false` property? What for an empty string property? Maybe this could be enough to tell if the property exists.

Answer (score 15):

If I understood your question correct here is an answer.

This would check if notificationFormat exists in your json.

```
$.subscription[?(@.notificationFormat)]
```

That would get all destinationAddress in case if notificationFormat exists

```
$.subscription[?(@.notificationFormat)].destinationAddress
```

Comment: The key part of the above solution is the JSONPath filter expression syntax "[?@.<property-name>]". You can test the expression by using an online JSONPath evaluator, such as the one provided by the Jayway JsonPath project at http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/.

If you're using Jayway's Java implementation of JSONPath - the JsonPath library - then there is also an alternative solution. See my answer below.

Comment: @NeilBrown, I am curious is there a way of selecting nodes that **do not** contain specific subnode?

Answer (score 1):

```
    ReadContext ctx = JsonPath.parse("{}", com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration.defaultConfiguration().addOptions(Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS));

    assertThat(ctx.read("$.components"), nullValue());
```

Comment: confirmed, if add a no exception configuration, it will result a null value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jayway's Java implementation of JSONPath - the [JsonPath library](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) - and parsing the JSON once, ahead of time, to make multiple reads more efficient, then there is an arguably clearer (than using a JSONPath filter expression) way to check whether an optional JSON property exists. Use the ReadContext object representation of the parsed JSON to return the parent JSON object as a Java HashMap, then check whether a map entry exists with the property's name. Using the JSON from the question, the (Java) code to check whether the optional 'notificationFormat' property exists would be -

```
ReadContext parsedJson = JsonPath.parse(jsonString);
HashMap subscription = parsedJson.read("$.subscription"); 
if (subscription.containsKey("notificationFormat")) {  
  ... 
}
```

Comment: What to do , if it is a nested JSON array ?